# How to change the size of JTextField?

Tags: java

So I am trying to make a JTextField a little bit bigger, using  `jtf.setSize(200,200);` but it is not working. Also, I am using a LayoutManager, this is the code: `jf.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));` (jf is JFrame)
So it is still the default size.
I also have a JButton next to the text field.
How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't setSize for Swing objects if you're using a LayoutManager. 
Try using setPreferredSize or setColumns

Comment: Thank you! I tried with setPreferredSize and it is working.